# Getting garbled output from fgets() in C

Tags: c, fgets

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  FILE *fp = fopen("sss", "w+");
  char buf[100];
  fputs("hello, world", fp);
  fflush(fp);
  fgets(buf, 100, fp);
  fputs(buf, stdout);
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

Can someone teach me what's wrong with my code? Below is my test, but I didn't get what I expected:

```
% clang test.c
% ./a.out
��h��%  
% cat test.c
hello, world%
```

My assumption is that this is a problem of character encoding, but when I use fgets to read the text from an existing file, it works fine. All my files (and code) are written in Emacs, I don't know what causes this garbled output

Comment: should close and reopen the file in read mode.. and add proper error handling

Comment: use `rewind` before  `fgets`.

Comment: Note: always check for the success of `fopen()`.

Comment: @amdixon - "w+" means "**Open for reading and writing**. The file is created if it does not exist, otherwise it is truncated. The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file." per http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen

Comment: @BLUEPIXY - `fseek()` works too.  http://linux.die.net/man/3/fseek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fp` is at the end after you write. Move it to initial position before using [`fseek`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseek.3.html) reading again:

```
fflush(fp);
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
fgets(buf, 100, fp);
```

Other option is to [`fclose`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fclose.3.html) it and [`fopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) it again. It depends on what you want to do.

Comment: And clean the buffer before reading, and maybe after creating.

Comment: @AlexKroll What you do mean by "clean"? `fflush` would flush any buffered output.

Comment: I mean `memset(buf, 0, 100)`.

Comment: `memset` is needless. Just checking the return of `fgets` should be enough. OP should error checking for all library functions.

Comment: It's the problem of stream position. I use fseek and succeed, thanks

Comment: Agree. Just for sure but not necessarily.